# subquery returning more than 1 values

Tags: sql

```
SELECT user_info.s_name, user_info.name, user_info.f_name, user_info.usr_id, user_info.img_path, Village_master.v_nm 
FROM Village_master 
INNER JOIN User_reg_master ON Village_master.v_id = User_reg_master.v_id 
INNER JOIN user_info ON User_reg_master.usr_id = user_info.usr_id 
WHERE user_info.usr_id NOT LIKE @u_id 
AND user_info.usr_id NOT LIKE (
    SELECT pers_dict_master.pers_dict_ids 
    FROM pers_dict_ids 
    WHERE pers_dict_master.usr_id=@u_id
)
```

**usr_id**|           **pers_dict_usr_id**

1 |                    13

1 |                     6

Comment: Use NOT IN instead of NOT LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is this ,

```
user_info.usr_id NOT LIKE
  (SELECT pers_dict_master.pers_dict_ids
   FROM pers_dict_ids
   WHERE pers_dict_master.usr_id=@u_id)
```

This is your sub query

```
  (SELECT pers_dict_master.pers_dict_ids
   FROM pers_dict_ids
   WHERE pers_dict_master.usr_id=@u_id)
```

It is fetching two columns.But In the `LIKE` command you are using a one Column.

So make it work USE `NOT IN`COMMAND

```
SELECT user_info.s_name,
       user_info.name,
       user_info.f_name,
       user_info.usr_id,
       user_info.img_path,
       Village_master.v_nm
FROM Village_master
INNER JOIN User_reg_master ON Village_master.v_id = User_reg_master.v_id
INNER JOIN user_info ON User_reg_master.usr_id = user_info.usr_id
WHERE user_info.usr_id NOT LIKE @u_id
  AND user_info.usr_id NOT IN
    ( SELECT pers_dict_master.pers_dict_ids
     FROM pers_dict_ids
     WHERE pers_dict_master.usr_id=@u_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include some more detail about your issue. Is the sub query expected to return more than one result? If so then you could simply use TOP(ie. select top 1 ...) to get just a single result and add an ORDER BY to the sub query if you want to get a certain sorted top value from that result set.

If the issue is that the sub query returns more than 1 result when it shouldn't, then your problem lies deeper. It looks like you may have meant to use IN for the subquery and for a different comparison, but it's difficult to tell. Perhaps you meant this?:

```
user_info.usr_id NOT IN
    (SELECT pers_dict_master.pers_dict_ids
         FROM pers_dict_ids WHERE pers_dict_master.usr_id=@u_id)
```